2005/6 French movie with graphic suicide
In early 2006 (Jan-March), I saw a movie with an unforgettable scene: a man sitting a table cuts his own throat with a knife.
I saw it at a theater in Toulouse, France. It was most likely in French, though possibly Spanish.
Not positive that this is the same movie, but I also remember an opening scene of a very long (at least 5 minutes) and far away shot of a guy sitting in a stadium.
Can anyone tell me the name of this movie?

The first scene you mentioned reminds me of a similar shocking suicide scene in Michael Haneke's Cache, but I don't remember any stadiums there (and I recently rewatched it). It does, however, contain a static, long opening shot from a distance, as well as several others like that.

Yes, I think that's it! So what/where is the opening scene then, if not a stadium? I just vaguely remember a guy sitting for ages, with nothing happening.

I'm not sure there is a scene like that there (perhaps you are thinking of a scene from another film). The opening shot of this one is a static shot of an apartment shot from a short distance. Amazing film, BTW.

OK. In any case, you're definitely right about the important scene, so please post it as an answer so I can accept. Thanks!

People sitting for ages with nothing happening definitely describes this movie. I don't recall any stadiums, though.

The suicide scene you mentioned is from Michael Haneke's Cache from 2005 and is indeed shocking. The person in question is near a chair but isn't seated when he does it, though. It can be seen here (WARNING: Graphic) and the trailer is below. A powerful scene in a very good film.



